# 26 hr Layover at London Heathrow (Transiting)

Tags: layovers, london, qatar

My dad is travelling from Cayman Island to London Heathrow on may 6 arriving at terminal 5. He has a lay over for 26 hours and has a next flight going to Qatar, then Qatar to Philippines.

I’ve read and research that the airside are not open 24 hrs so no matter what it takes he has step out & find somewhere to stay like hotels nearby the airport. To be able to do it he need to obtain a transit visa right? Can a transit visa be granted in the airport or at border control?

Comment: Please add the **citizenship** of the person to the question.

Comment: If your father needs a transit visa he will have to apply from outside the UK. UK Border control do not issue visas on arrival (of any type).

Comment: @Traveller and the passenger would probably not even be allowed to board the first flight without a visa.

Comment: Also, are all flights on the same ticket/booking? What airlines are involved? From which terminal will he be departing? Will he have checked luggage? Please edit your question to add those details (along with the most important one, his citizenship).

Answer (score 4):

We don't know the nationality of your father, or whether he has any relevant residency permits, but it is more than likely he will indeed need a transit visa.

**You can check whether he needs one using the UK government [check if you need a visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) website.**

Transit visas, like any other visa, need to be applied for in advance. **No visas are granted at the airport. Without a visa, your father is probably not even going to be allowed to board the flight to the UK.**

Note that even in the event he were **able to stay airside, depending on his nationality and permits, he may need a "direct airside transit visa" (DATV)**. This is different from some other countries where you never need a visa as long as you stay airside. Again, the visa check website will tell you so.

To get a more precise answer, please edit your question with details of:

- Your father's nationality.
- Any residency permits / long term visas he may hold, especially from countries like the US, Canada, Australia, New Zealand or European countries.
- Whether the two flights are on the same ticket/booking (single PNR).
- The airlines involved.
- Whether he will have checked luggage.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a full answer to your question but more of a comment (I don't have enough reputation at the time to post a comment).*

Some airlines offer free hotel stay if you have a long layover, they might also give you information on whether you need a transit visa or not and how to obtain it.

A quick search and you will find websites with lists of concerned airlines and the criteria to meet :

- https://www.sleepinginairports.net/airlines-provide-free-hotels-long-layovers.htm
- https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/team-blog/2019/05/how-to-get-a-free-hotel-from-your-airline-on-a-long-stopover-tra/